# What is the point of modulating an adf loop antenna output with a voltage switching source through a balanced modulator?

Tags: ndb

In the block diagram I found for the ADF system, there is a balanced modulator fed with the output signal from the ADF loop antenna and a 47Hz signal from a switching source. What does the output from this balanced modulator looks like and what is the point of doing this?
[image]